# Set length of a column vector equal to the length of a submatrix

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, vector, string-length

I am trying to use the convhull function in a loop and for that I need to split matrices into submatrices of different sizes. Here is the code I am using:

```
    x1=data(:,5); % x centre location
    y1=data(:,16); % y centre location
    z1=phi*90; % phi angle value
    n=300;
    %Create regular grid across data space
    [X,Y] = meshgrid(linspace(min(x1),max(x1),n), linspace(min(y1),max(y1),n));

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%% PLOT USING SCATTER - TRYING TO ISOLATE SOME REGIONS %%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    c=z1>10 & z1 < 20;
    c=c.*1;
    j=1;
    for i=1:length(z1)
        if z1(i)< 20 && z1(i)> 10
            c(i) = 1;
        else
            c(i)= 0;
        end       
    end


    C=[c c c];
C = ~C;

elementalLengthA = cellfun('length',regexp(sprintf('%i',all(C,2)),'1+','match'));
elementalStartA = regexp(sprintf('%i',all(C,2)),'1+','start');
result = cell(length(elementalLengthA),1);



 for i = 1:length(elementalLengthA)
    result(i) = {C(elementalStartA(i):elementalStartA(i)+elementalLengthA(i)-1,:)};
    length(x1(i))=length(cell2mat(result(i)));
    length(y1(i))=length(cell2mat(result(i)));
end
```

My for loop doens't work properly and I get this error: ??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or
logicals.

My matrix C is an nx3 matrix made of lines of 1 and 0. With the result(i) line I am splitting the C matrix into submatrices of 1. Let's say

```
c = [1     1     1;
     0     0     0;
     0     0     0;
     1     1     1;
     1     1     1;
     1     1     1;
     0     0     0;
     1     1     1;
     1     1     1;]
```

Then

```
>> cell2mat(result(1))
ans =
 1     1     1

>> cell2mat(result(2))
ans =
 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 1     1     1

>> cell2mat(result(3))
ans =
 1     1     1
 1     1     1
```

Now x1 and y1 are two vector column nx1. And I want to split them according to the length of C submatrices. so length(x1(1)) should be 1, length(x1(2))=3, length(x1(3))=2 and same for the y vector. 
Is it possible to do that?

EDIT: 
Just to make it more clear
For instance

```
x1 =

     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
     9
```

and

```
y1 =

     2
     4
     6
     8
    10
    12
    14
    16
    18
```

I want to get this as an output:

```
x1(1)=[1], x1(2)=[4 5 6]' and x1(3)=[8 9]'
y1(1)=[2], y1(2)[8 10 12]' and y1(3)=[16 18]'
```

Thanks
Dorian

Comment: you cannot impose `length` function to the left side of assignment. thats the error. whats your initial value of `X1` & `Y1`.. after splitting `X1` & `Y1` what do you think the result might look like?

Comment: For instance in my real code when I do
`length(x1)` I get 96616
`length(cell2mat(result(1)))=354`
and I want to index the vector x1 to have `length(x1(1))=354` too
Let me edit the question

Comment: what is the value of data?

Comment: do you wanna split X into X1, X2.. according to the length of result(1), result(2)... ??

Comment: I edited the question with an example

Comment: if you have given this example earlier, i wouldn't have asked you to post this as a new question.. i'll answer this in previous question